# cant do clearInterval inside ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I am doing ajax request to get the updates on from database to show progress bar.
Everything is working except when the interval has to stop it doesnot. Already searched a lot but doesnot work.
Here is my code

```
var SMS = {
    start: function () {
        SMS.intervalID = window.setInterval(SMS.update, SMS.interval);
    },
    update: function () {
        var config = {
            ajax: {
                url: '/update'
            }
        };

        var req = new APP.request(config);
        APP.request.prototype.done = function (data) {

            if (data !== '0') {

                var curData = JSON.parse(data);

                var SMSDATA = JSON.parse(curData.queue_data);

                //now lets update the dom
                var totalSms = SMSDATA.total;
                var sentSms = SMSDATA.sent;
                $(".smsSent").text(sentSms);
                $(".smsTotal").text(totalSms);
                $("#smsProgress progress").prop('max', totalSms).prop('value', sentSms);

                SMS.counter++;

            } else {

                console.log(SMS.intervalID)
                window.clearInterval(SMS.intervalID);
                $(".smsQueueModal").modal();

            }
        };
        req.sendNow();
    }
};
```

In this code everything runs ok but after the return data is 0
it keeps on firing the else part of the condition . window.clearInterval is not working.
Both of my logs on console shows the same value for the **IntervalID**

I dont think scope is the problem because is have tired other ways also. Defining the intervalID outside of the function and so on.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well what value does it show for the interval id?

Comment: numeric value but changes for every time i do it again by refreshing the browser like 2,3 ....

Comment: the value is same in both places of the response condition

Comment: Add a `console.log()` call in the "start" routine (make sure you label the log messages so you can tell which is which; like, `console.log("start: " + SMS.intervalID);` ) - maybe you're overwriting the value.

Comment: value is same like start 6, but is being called twice for each interval ?? any ideas

Comment: If the "start" function is called twice, the id of the original interval will be lost. Initialize the id to `null`, and then in "start" you can throw an error if the id already has a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript timers(setInterval,setTimeout) are not efficient because they continue to run when browser window is minimized or other tab is open , thereby wasting CPU cycles.

Sometimes it can happen that callback function takes more time to complete (due to network latency , db latency etc) than what was assigned to the timer function . So before callback functions completes , timer will fire another function call and enqueue other callback function , when previous one was not completed. As this process continues for a time ,many callbacks functions are enqueue and timer does not stop when it is required(after clearing setInterval)

So here make sure to clearInterval before assigning it again or use a flag with setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame